# solr 5.3 - suggest feature not working

Tags: autosuggest, solr5

I added the search component and the request handler in the solrconfig.xml file, but I get an error saying

> "No suggester named default was configured" when I type 
>   `../../suggest?suggest.q=A&wt=json&suggest.build=true&indent=true&debugQuery=true` in the browser

Comment: Okay I got the fix, The name of the /suggest module in the handler was different from what I had given in the search component tag :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Suppose your search component is:

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
 <lst name="suggester">
   <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
             ...
 </lst>
```

**First way:**

You must add "dictionary" parameter to your request handler default parameters as follows:

```
<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler">
 <lst name="defaults">
   <str name="suggest.dictionary">mySuggester</str>
   <str name="suggest">true</str>
   <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
 </lst>
 <arr name="components">
   <str>suggest</str>
 </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

**Second way:**

If you haven't specified "dictionary" parameter in your request handler default parameters, you must add it to URL.

For example:

```
<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler">
 <lst name="defaults">
   <str name="suggest">true</str>
   <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
 </lst>
 <arr name="components">
   <str>suggest</str>
 </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

Then you can use following url:

```
../../suggest?suggest.dictionary=mySuggester&q=A&wt=json&suggest.build=true&indent=true&debugQuery=true
```