# Solr 9 – Error "No suggester named suggest was configured"

Tags: solr, lucene, solrcloud

I am new to Solr and am trying to add the [Suggest Search Component](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/suggester.html#adding-the-suggest-search-component) via the [Config API](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/configuration-guide/config-api.html).

My Solr 9.0.0 setup is as follows:

1. `bin/solr start -e cloud`  with _default config
2. Index a csv with `bin/post -c collection_name file_path/file.csv`
3. Add the search component with a POST request to `http://localhost:8983/api/collections/collection_name/config`:

```
{
  "add-searchcomponent": {
    "name": "suggest",
    "class": "solr.SuggestComponent",
    "lookupImpl": "FuzzyLookupFactory",
    "dictionaryImpl": "DocumentDictionaryFactory",
    "field": "name",
    "suggestAnalyzerFieldType": "string",
    "buildOnStartup": false
  }
}
```

4. Add the request handler with a POST request to `http://localhost:8983/api/collections/collection_name/config`:

```
{
  "add-requesthandler": {
    "name": "/suggest",
    "startup": "lazy",
    "class": "solr.SearchHandler",
    "defaults": {
                    "suggest": true,
                    "suggest.count": 10
                },
    "components": ["suggest"]
  }
}
```

This works fine and my configoverlay.json looks as follows:

```
{
  "props":{"updateHandler":{"autoSoftCommit":{"maxTime":3000}}},
  "searchComponent":{"suggest":{
      "name":"suggest",
      "class":"solr.SuggestComponent",
      "lookupImpl":"FuzzyLookupFactory",
      "dictionaryImpl":"DocumentDictionaryFactory",
      "field":"name",
      "suggestAnalyzerFieldType":"string",
      "buildOnStartup":false}},
  "requestHandler":{"/suggest":{
      "name":"/suggest",
      "startup":"lazy",
      "class":"solr.SearchHandler",
      "defaults":{
        "suggest":true,
        "suggest.count":10},
      "components":["suggest"]}}}
```

But if I send the request `http://localhost:8983/solr/collection_name/suggest?suggest.dictionary=suggest&q=J&suggest.build=true` I receive the following error:

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "zkConnected": true,
        "status": 400,
        "QTime": 3
    },
    "error": {
        "metadata": [
            "error-class",
            "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
            "root-error-class",
            "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"
        ],
        "msg": "No suggester named suggest was configured",
        "code": 400
    }
}
```

I could imagine it has something to do with the naming of the search component, as there are two distinct names as defined in the [docs](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/suggester.html#suggester-search-component-parameters). There is a "searchComponent name" and a "name" parameter, but I don't now how to manipulate the "searchComponent name".

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35146453/solr-5-3-suggest-feature-not-working) and [this](http://www.coldat.com/2019/02/25/sitecore-suggest-no-suggester-named-default-was-configured/) post on a similar error, but both posts are about the suggest.dictionary not being configured which is not the case in my situation.

Any help on what I am doing wrong is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One SuggestComponent can use multiple dictionaries, so you have to define them in a list and specify a `name` explicitly for each one.

Note also that `buildOnStartup` expects a string.

```
{
  "add-searchcomponent": {
    "name": "suggest",
    "class": "solr.SuggestComponent",
    "suggester": [{
      "name": "fuzzy",
      "lookupImpl": "FuzzyLookupFactory",
      "dictionaryImpl": "DocumentDictionaryFactory",
      "field": "name",
      "suggestAnalyzerFieldType": "string",
      "buildOnStartup": "false"
    }]
  }
}
```

Which you can query with `.../suggest?suggest.dictionary=fuzzy&q=J&suggest.build=true`

Comment: Thanks a lot, also for being so attentive and noticing the buildOnStartup error! This has solved my problem. Were did you find this? I have spent quite some time in the docs and couldn't find anything about how to build concrete config requests.

Comment: This is not explicitly mentioned in the doc, but basically you can guess the structure from the regular xml config : we can have [multiple dictionaries](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/suggester.html#multiple-dictionaries), that is, multiple `<lst name="suggester">...</lst>`, which translates to `"suggester": []`, and each of them must define a set of string properties `<str name="propertyName">propertyValue</str>`, which translates to `{"propertyName": "propertyValue", ...}`.